# Using Angular Select, after selecting value, ng-model is null

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How do I keep `$scope.model.AvaliableCustomers` from getting set to `null`?

My select pulldown option seems to work correctly up until after I select a value. Once I select a value, instead of showing the selection, the model is cleared and nothing appears for a selection options  other than the initial default "-- Select --". The model & option list disappears.

I tried this with a `ng-change` event and can see that the event is triggered two times after making a selection. The first time the model is populated and variables inside customerChange seems to work fine. For a reason unknown to me, the event immediately occurs a second time - now `$scope.model.AvaliableCustomers` is `null` and my select list is empty. How do I keep `$scope.model.AvaliableCustomers` from getting stomped on?

```
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.model =
    {
        "CustomerProfileId": 0,
        "CustomerName": null,
        "AvaliableCustomers": [
            {
                "CustomerName": "John Doe",
                "CustomerProfileId": 1,
                "IsSelected": true
            },
            {
                "CustomerName": "Janit Doe",
                "CustomerProfileId": 2,
                "IsSelected": true
            },
            {
                "CustomerName": "Mark Doe",
                "CustomerProfileId": 3,
                "IsSelected": true
            },
            {
                "CustomerName": "Lisa Doe",
                "CustomerProfileId": 4,
                "IsSelected": true
            },
        ]
    }
};

$scope.customerChange = function () {
    $scope.parameters.customerId = $scope.model.AvaliableCustomers.CustomerProfileId;
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customers">Customer</label>
        <select id="selectCustomerId" class="form-control"
                ng-change="customerChange()"
                ng-model="model.AvaliableCustomers"
                ng-options="c.CustomerName for c in model.AvaliableCustomers">
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an Angular question, but an AngularJS question. Please don't use the `angular` tag.

Comment: On your `<select>`, why is `ng-model` set to `model.AvailableCustomers`? That's a collection. Are you wanting to set `$scope.model.CustomerProfileId` to whatever is selected?

Comment: `ng-model` uses `model.AvaliableCustomers`  because `CustomerName` represents my list of items to display and `CustomerProfileId`  represents the list of values to select from. `$scope.model.AvaliableCustomers.CustomerProfileId` will show the value selected.

Comment: `ng-options` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I keep `$scope.model.AvaliableCustomers` from getting stomped on?

Use a different scope variable for the `ng-model` directive:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customers">Customer</label>
        <select id="selectCustomerId" class="form-control"
                ng-change="customerChange()"
                ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶.̶A̶v̶a̶l̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶C̶u̶s̶t̶o̶m̶e̶r̶s̶"̶
                ng-model="somethingElse"
                ng-options="c.CustomerName for c in model.AvaliableCustomers">
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)
- [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: That's helpful, looking at the reference, ng-model needs to be different than ng-options.